# Setting value of date input in protractor test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, protractor, appium

I am developing an Ionic hybrid mobile application and am in the middle of writing some protractor tests. I am using Appium for testing it against a simulator version of the app.

I have a registration form with various inputs including a date input:
`<input type="date" name="dob" ng-model="vm.register.dob" ng-max="vm.dobMax" required>`

In my test, I am able to populate all the text inputs by calling, for example:
`input.sendKeys("John Doe");`

However, I can't seem to populate the date input. I have tried:
`var dobInput = element(by.model('vm.register.dob'));
dobInput.sendKeys("01-01-2015");
dobInput.sendKeys("01012015");`

I have even just tried to click on the input to force the native date picker to appear:
dobInput.click();

None of these things work and I am unable to fill the date input with a value.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Check that the date format fits the acceptable date input format, e.g.:

```
dobInput.sendKeys("2015-01-01");
```

Comment: So turns out it was the format of the string. When I set it to "2015-01-01" it works, but doesn't need any of the clicks. Ta

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to the format `item.name` in your code to access `by.model` :

```
var dobInput = element(by.model('input.vm.register.dob'));
dobInput.click();
dobInput.sendKeys("01-01-2015");
```